# To keep or not to keep: attic panels in a closet

Tags: drywall, storage, closet, access-panel

I have two of these wall panels in a walk in closet:

[image]

Behind them is crawl space over a garage ceiling:

[image]

I’d like to remove the panels and replace with flat drywall, effectively closing this space off permanently.

In regard to the integrity of the home; is there any important reason I should *not* close off this space? I’m fine with eliminating the small amount of potential storage in exchange for a nicer closet finish.

Comment: Is there kind of wiring or plumbing /vents in that space? If none of the above I don't see any problems with closing it off. Personaly I would leave it accessible but it is your home.

Comment: None of the above. If there were ever an issue inside the space I think it would be repaired outside. All around that space is exterior siding, garage drywall ceiling, roofing, and the room attached to the closet. Other than storage I can’t fathom a reason I would ever access it. Would future owners prefer more attic style storage? I think the answer to that is opinion based.

Comment: I would agree if there is nothing in there and you don't want it I don't see a reason to keep it.

Comment: If future home owners want access to this space, it would be easy for them an access hole at that time.

Comment: Well, YDWYL, but "its a closet" - not like these nicely trimmed access panels are in your living room. Reasons other than storage you might want to get in there without ripping a hole in the siding - to check for / locate a roof leak, to run wires, to not expensively damage the siding to access it for whatever reason. I have come to hate past owners or builders with your mindset about making significant spaces inaccessible. But I'm probably not going to buy your house. @PaulLogan it will be non-obvious to a future owner where to cut for an access panel once this wall becomes blank drywall.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. It sounds like it's a better idea to just keep the panels in place.